# Telerik: Search Bar Component not Seen/Located for .Net Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, kendo-ui, telerik

Does Telerik have a Search Bar Component for .Net Core?

I see one for .Net Ajax, however did not locate anything for .Net Core. Otherwise I will use Masked Text Box.

https://www.telerik.com/products/aspnet-ajax/searchbox.aspx

Comment: Is RadSearchBox working on ASP.NET Core?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not called SearchBar, but you can use the [AutoComplete](https://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-core/autocomplete/index) component.

There is a [sample](https://docs.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/tutorials/tutorial-saleshub/order-page/kendo-saleshub-search-box) for ASP.NET MVC. It should be the same for ASP.NET Core.

Kind regards
Bernd